# Nodejs app crashing frequently

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nodemon

I am using `gulp-nodemon` to restart the nodejs server frequently on changes in `server.js` file.

Here is the excerpt code from `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'site'))); //  "public" off of current is root

app.listen(9090, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 9090!');
});

app.get('/getProducts', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.query);

  res.send({
    hey: "hello"
  });
});
```

I am getting the following error frequently:

[image]

I even tried changing the ports (`netstat -a`). Sometimes the nodejs server works and sometimes it doesn't.

PS: I am on Windows 8

Comment: You have 2 `app.listen()` calls

Comment: @Ananth thanks I updated. I can still see the same error.

Comment: can you try to check is there any other file or process is using the port `9090`? maybe with something like `lsof -i` or something?

Comment: @kucing_terbang I am on windows. I already checked it with `netstat -a`.

Comment: Which line is line 13 of server.js? Is it `app.listen(9090,...`? Then there definitely is something already listening on 9090. What is your `gulp-nodemon` setting? Maybe you are having similar issues to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404954/gulp-nodemon-node-error-listen-eaddrinuse? What is your node and nodemon version? Maybe the do not play well together as mentioned here: http://domainwebcenter.com/?topic=nodemon?

Comment: @migg yes, the line 13 is `app.listen...` I am sure nothing is running on `9090`. I even tried changing the port number, the error persists. node version is `v5.0.0` and gulp-nodemon version is `2.0.6`. Thanks I am checking your links.